# What's the difference in meaning and usage between 'post' and 'posting'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Both **post** and **posting** are the same according to Cambridge Dictionary (*Android version*). Both have the same meaning i.e.

> an electronic message that you send to a website in order to allow
> many people to see it

Anyway, these are the screenshots that I took:

[image]

[image]

Related to the question, what's the difference? To give a particular example, suppose, I want to refer something that uploaded by someone on social media, is it a post or a posting?

P.S. Please use a vpn if the images can't be seen. It's probably your country blocked the imgur feature. That works  on me. It's difficult to tell what's on the screnshoot when the definition of both two are exactly the same.

Comment: Please type text. Don't use screenshots or images.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey what's the problem with the screenshots? It helps people to know whether probably there's the difference from the picture! If I typed it, people won't know!

Comment: You should re-type the text. Screen shots or images are not indexable by search engines.

Comment: Screenshots are also not accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I've edited the question anyway. As I said before, I provided the screenshots to help the answerer to tell me whether I missed something. I've never been criticized providing the screenshots before... It did help people to answer my previous question in this group by providing the screenshot. I hope this is not because I post too much in this site and then people start to hate me. I'm a serious learner and here, I need your help.

Comment: @user516076  No Problem here. I had not encountered any of your previous posts, I was just trying to help you understand why many prefer text to images. I have no negative feelings to you, and hope you ask as many questions as yu can use help with. I for one enjoy providing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word that everybody uses for this purpose is "post." As the dictionary says, "posting" (as a noun) is also possible, but relatively rare.